# Проблема подключения jquery

Tags: javascript, linux

Товарищи! Скачал **libjs-jquery** на linux-ubuntu через терминал. Так как неизвестно на какую директорию, то не до конца понимаю как ее подключить к странице. Через *CDN* не хочу.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704564/how-to-use-libjs-jquery-debian-package-in-a-project

Comment: О спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Вот так, с помощью нехитрых приспособлений буханку белого (или черного) хлеба можно превратить в троллейбус...

Исходя из списка файлов, umd дистрибутив js библиотеки лежит в `/usr/share/javascript/jquery/`. Достучаться до этой папки продакшн веб-сервером может оказаться не тривиальной задачей, быстрее всего будет скопировать html файлы прямо туда и развернуть встроенный в python3 http сервер командой `python3 -m http.server` прямо в той папке. Однако, если вы не хотите работать с зависимостями на удаленных ресурсах, я бы сделал по другому...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуйте установить jquery из npm, вынуть из папки node_modules файл с собранной библиотекой и переместить в отдельную папку с сторонними зависимостями, сохранив версию из package.json в наименовании на подобие того, как это сделано в [этом](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/material-ui-umd) репозитории для создания обособленного от интернета диструбутива React компонентов в стиле Material. После, node_modules можно будет удалить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подобная практика особо хороша в академических целях при участии на хакатонах с ограничением доступа к интернету и при одиночной работе, но сомнительна при работе в команде. Для каждой задачи есть свой инструмент

Answer (score 0):

Если html, то можно просто через google:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```